# drag image from TileList and drop on Canvas in Flex 3

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, canvas, drag-and-drop, flex3

i'm working on a Flex project where i will have to use the drag & drop functionality.
i have a TileList filled with images as items, and a Canvas. i used the tilelist's **"dragEnabled"** and **"dragMoveEnabled"** properties to make the images (items) dragable,but can't make the canvas a dropable area.

i'm new to flex by the way, so please make it simple.
and thank you

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop capabilities can be manually added to any non-list based control. Take a look at:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cfc.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d03

If you are still struggling after trying to implement the above, post some code and I will be happy to help more.

Answer (score 0):

i ended up making this code!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
//Import classes####################################################################
import mx.managers.DragManager;
import mx.core.DragSource;
import mx.events.DragEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// IMAGES ###########################################################################

[Bindable]
[Embed(source="assets/images/thumb/1.jpg")]
public var photo1:Class;            

[Bindable]
[Embed(source="assets/images/thumb/2.jpg")]
public var photo2:Class;


// FUNCTIONS ###########################################################################

import mx.core.DragSource;
import mx.managers.DragManager;
import mx.events.DragEvent;
import mx.controls.Alert;

private function dragEnterHandler(event:DragEvent):void {
if (event.dragSource.hasFormat("items")){
DragManager.acceptDragDrop(Canvas(event.currentTarget));
}
}

private function dragDropHandler(event:DragEvent):void {

}



]]>
</mx:Script>




<!-- ######## CONTROLS ############################################################ -->


<!-- canvas -->
<mx:Canvas dragDrop="{dragDropHandler(event)}" dragEnter="{dragEnterHandler(event)}" x="395" y="10" width="436" height="486" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF">
</mx:Canvas>

<!-- tile list -->
<mx:TileList    x="0" y="10" height="100%" width="154" columnCount="1" id="tl"  maxColumns="1"  dragEnabled="true" dragMoveEnabled="false" allowMultipleSelection="false"  >
<mx:dataProvider>
<mx:Array>
<mx:Object label="photo 1" icon="{photo1}" data="photo" />
<mx:Object label="photo 2" icon="{photo2}" data="photo" />
</mx:Array>
</mx:dataProvider>
</mx:TileList>  


</mx:Application>
```

the canvas now accepts my drag, but when i drop the image on to it, the image just disappears. i know i have to create a function to handle the DragDrop event but i don't really know how to get the dragSource image.
any help .. i'll be grateful